# How does this field multiplication in libsecp256k1 work?

Tags: cryptography, secp256k1, math

I'm looking at libsecp256k1's codebase, for learning reasons (doubt I can contribute with anything useful there). While looking at the field implementation, the implementation of `secp256k1_fe_mul_inner` in both [10x26](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1/blob/77af1da9f631fa622fb5b5895fd27be431432368/src/field_10x26_impl.h#L408) and 5x52 is a little strange to me. I know some multiplication algorithms, like Karatsuba and Toom's algorithms, but this one doesn't look like one of them, at least I couldn't relate.
Looking at the source and git history, I only see a reference to Peter Dettman, but I was unable to find any paper authored by him. Is this algorithm inspired by a public paper? Any reference would be helpful, as I'm unable to follow reason about the code itself. I understand what it is doing, but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: I am not sure whether I should post this as an answer (can I just answer with a couple of links?), anyway have a look at this: https://free-cy.blogspot.com/2020/04/mathematics-behind-secp256k1femulinner.html , which I have found from here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5425925

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio I would recommend posting an answer with links and a summary of details from the first link.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this algorithm inspired by a public paper?
> Any reference would be helpful, as I'm unable
> to follow reason about the code itself.

I am not sure about "papers", but more or less formal articles on *modular multiplication* in fact abound: indeed, the implementation in question "simply" leverages known properties of modular arithmetic.

As to the specifics, the following is the link to a post about an older and somewhat simpler version of `secp256k1_fe_mul_inner` than the current one, but it might be enough to support further exploration/reverse-engineering:

- @cycheng, "Mathematics behind secp256k1_fe_mul_inner", 2020
  https://free-cy.blogspot.com/2020/04/mathematics-behind-secp256k1femulinner.html

That article also contains a link to the relevant modular arithmetic, in a nice and compact series of slides, which I will repost here:

- Peter Schwabe, "Efficient implementation of finite-field arithmetic," 2013
  https://cryptojedi.org/peter/data/pairing-20131122.pdf

(There could be some added value in explaining the *present* implementation of `secp256k1_fe_mul_inner`, since it adds few more optimizations on top of the basic modular arithmetic.  But I think that would require a level of detail and formality that is well beyond the scope of the present question.)